# Replacing @ with % in a string (using only batch scripting)

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to replace the @ string with a %40 to pass to a web browser using only a batch file.  What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
set _FOO=test@some.com
set _BAR=%_FOO:@=_40%
set _BAR

_BAR=test_40some.com
```

This is almost what I want, but I need that _ to be a % (as in "test%40some.com").  However, there doesn't seem to be a way to escape the % symbol.  Neither of these work:

```
set _BAR=%_FOO:@=\%40%
set _BAR=%_FOO:@=%%40%
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _FOO=test@example.com
set "_BAR=!_FOO:@=%%40!"

echo %_BAR%
```

Delayed expansion helps here as it allows the »normal« metacharacters, such as %, to be used. For more information about delayed expansion see `help set`.